# Rspec fails with "bad value for range"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My method:

```
def swap (order)
   order = order == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'
end
```

Spec:

```
let(:order) { 'wrong_order'}

it 'swaps the order' do
 expect(swap(order)).to eq('asc')
end
```

This rspec is failing with the message `ArgumentError: bad value for range`

But if i pass 'desc' or 'asc' and change the expect it works fine.

Also i tried this on irb with just passing swap(' ') it gives me 'asc' not sure why rspec is failing

Comment: This spec _in particular_ is failing? I'm not sure I see any reason why this would case a `bad value for range` error.

Comment: i know there is no reason for it to give 'bad value for range' its strange.

Comment: Please identify the specific source line that is failing, per the stacktrace.  Also, if it really is on the line you think it is, please check `method(:swap).source_location` to make sure the version of `swap` you are picking up is the one you showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try being a bit more explicit with the test:

```
let(:order) { 'wrong_order'}

it 'swaps the order' do
  swapped_order = swap(order)

  expect(swapped_order).to eq('asc')
end
```